# how to sign raw transaction with python

Tags: transactions, python

I know there is a wallet called MyEtherWallet can sign with private key offline, and there seems to be javascript library that can also do this, but is there a python library or any code that can sign the raw transaction provided that I have private key string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options. `Account.signTransaction` in `web3.py` is one such option: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/blob/master/docs/web3.eth.account.rst.

Comment: that's great help

Answer (score 5):

> is there a python library or any code that can sign the raw transaction provided that I have private key string?

There is module called **Account** in [Web3.py](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). This module has [`signTransaction`](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.account.html?highlight=sign#web3.account.Account.signTransaction) method, which can be used like that:

```
transaction = {
        'to': '0xF0109fC8DF283027b6285cc889F5aA624EaC1F55',
        'value': 1000000000,
        'gas': 2000000,
        'gasPrice': 234567897654321,
        'nonce': 0,
        'chainId': 1
    }
key = '0x4c0883a69102937d6231471b5dbb6204fe5129617082792ae468d01a3f362318'
signed = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(transaction, key)

w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed.rawTransaction)
```

Comment: using this, I get this error: raise TypeError("Transaction had invalid fields: %r" % invalid)

Comment: @FedericoCaccia This appears to be an issue with addresses that are not checksummed https://github.com/ethereum/eth-account/issues/211